# Loading data from JavaScript object to table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the below code. Why am I not able to load data from the `article` object to the table row?

```js
 var article = {
 student: 'Eve Jackson',
 studentID: 'A0088888',
 articles:[[
             {title : "OOP Concepts", size : "Medium", printable:true}, {tags : ["C#", "Java", "Objective-c"]}, {weight : [1, 2, 1]}, 16, {extra : [0, 1.5, 0]}
            ] ,
            [
              {title : "Functional", size : "Large", printable:false}, {tags : ["JavaScript", "HTML", "PHP"]}, {weight : [2, 2, 1]}, 16, {extra : [0, 1.5, 0]}
            ] ,
            [
              {title : "Web", size : "Small", printable:true}, {tags : ["HTML", "CSS", "Angular","jQuery"]}, {weight : [3, 2, 1]}, 16, {extra : [0, 1.5, 0]}
            ] 
         ]
};

for (i = 0; i < article.articles.length; i++) { 
    $('#map').append('<tr><td>'+  article.articles[i][0].title+'</td></tr>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Topic</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Printable</th>
    <th>Tags</th>
  </tr>
<tbody id="map"></tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `article.articles[0][i].title` to `article.articles[i][0].title`

Answer (score 0):

Because can't loop in for yor code shoul be below

```
for (i = 0; i < article.articles[0].length; i++) {
```

Comment: Sorry it was my fault @kharhys 's answer is correct